# Role management user interface in cakePHP

Tags: user-interface, cakephp, acl, cakephp-1.3, ui-design

Is there any easy way to create a user interface to role management section(allow or deny permissions) for admin in cakePHP?

easy way means any inbuid helper or something?

Comment: almost got the solution https://sourceforge.net/projects/bancer/ but need some customization :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the bakery for the ACL plugin. This provides you with an admin interface (UI) for handling an existing aro/aco structure, at least the CRUD functionality (I have not played long with the plugin). If you don't have an aro/aco structure yet, follow the tutorial at the end of the manual.

If you simply look for a group based, individual based rights management, same tutorial could be all you need, as moving users between groups leads to different access rights.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no inbuilt helper to create this kind of functionality. Your best bet is to `cake bake` the MVC stack you've designed for this functionality.

Cake can do lots, but designing your application for you is probably out of scope :p